# Specify location(s) that work across several hostnames in Nginx

Tags: nginx

There are several sites with different hostnames served from my Nginx server. I'd like to serve nice-looking http errors that contain references to other files (one image in my case).

This is the config that makes the 404 error work for a specific hostname:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    ...

    location /http-error {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/http-error;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/http-error;
    }
}
```

This allows to specify all the files necessary for the nice-looking 404 error in the `/usr/share/nginx/http-error` directory.

But currently I have to repeat these lines for every server name. Is there a more effective way, to specify a global `location` directive that works accross every hostname, unless it is overwritten/disabled in the hostname's server block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have global aliases, as the [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive is only available inside `server` context (and another `location`, but that would eventually be inside a `server{}` block, too). The [`error_page`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) can be directly in `http{}` context, though. For the global (or repeated) aliases you could use an [`include`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include):

```
http {
    error_page  404  /404.html;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;
        include      /etc/nginx/global-aliases.conf;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.org;
        include      /etc/nginx/global-aliases.conf;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/global-aliases.conf`:

```
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/http-error;
}
```